# 'onmousedrag' event js

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some code that works each time onmouseclick and continuously onmousemove when I set them accordingly. I am looking for a way to combine the two (i.e. like a click and drag) which I thought would be a simple task but cannot find any simple explanation. The closest I get is drag-and-drop tutorials.

Do I have to call the onmousemove event while the onmouseclick event is triggered? Or is there something really simple I am completely overlooking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to just use a flag like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n3MeH/.

```
var isMouseDown = false;
document.onmousedown = function() { isMouseDown = true  };
document.onmouseup   = function() { isMouseDown = false };
document.onmousemove = function() { if(isMouseDown) { /* do drag things */ } };
```

Comment: Such a simple answer, can't believe I never thought of flags in events when the rest of my code is littered with them. Thanks

Comment: This does not work 100% if you wish to do the dragging on other elements than the document. If you start the drag on a canvas, or some other element, and dragging the mouse out of that element you will not get the onmouseup callback, thus getting the isMouseDown stick at true.

Comment: @Cort3z: Are you sure? Events bubble up with the end point being `document`. In fact, even if you release the mouse outside the browser window the `mouseup` event gets fired. At least that's what I'm experiencing in Chrome. Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n3MeH/6/) not work as described?

Comment: @pimvdb I was making a point in the case where you did not use the document as your element. Thus this method only works if you use it on the document element.

Comment: @Cort3z: You could bind `mousedown`/`mousemove` to the element and bind `mouseup` to the document. That should solve that issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use global variable for dragging, you can use `event.buttons` for determining which mouse button is pressed.

I tested this code in Chrome and Firefox.

```
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    if(event.buttons == 1) { //dragged with left mouse button
        //your code
    }

    if(event.buttons > 0) { //dragged with any mouse button
        //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('ex');

div.onmousedown = function(){
    document.onmousemove = function(e){
        div.innerText = '('+e.pageX +', '+e.pageY+')';
    }
    document.onmouseup = function(e){
        div.innerText = 'Click Me!';
        document.onmousemove = function(){};
    }
}
```

It binds the documents mousemove and mouseup event on the divs mousedown.

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/cSKq2/

Comment: @Joseph Haha Well done! It's basically a playable game now :)

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding correctly I think you just want to break your `onmouseclick` into `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` (like setting a draggable bool, and then revert it on mouse up...but since you said the closest you found is drag/drop info, maybe you mean something else?)

Answer (score 0):

really simple... I hope :)

when the mousedown event is triggered, set a global "dragging" variable to true.  Then when mouseup is triggered, set it to false.