# Is there a js event that being fired when selection starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run some code while user selecting a text. The 'while' is very important. onselect event is fired only after the text has been selected, so it doesn't help much.

Basically I have a situation that a very big message is being shown and it hides part of a paragraph. So I want to hide the message automatically if the user starts to select something in the paragraph.

Comment: Hope this thread will help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using flags (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819045/onmousedrag-event-js) question):

```
var isMouseDown = false;
document.getElementById("para").onmousedown = function () {
    isMouseDown = true;
};
document.getElementById("para").onmouseup = function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
    this.style.background = "white";
};
document.getElementById("para").onmousemove = function () {
    if (isMouseDown) { /* do drag things */
        this.style.background = "red";
    }
};
```

[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8fsmk1m/) (Try selecting the text and just clicking it).

Comment: As i understand OP's question, this is exactly what he is looking for